# Django variables in <script> tag

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I am trying to assign True or False to a javascript variable based on the value of a django template variable. My django template variable has many states(added,created,submitted and some more). I would like to give the value true to javascript variable, if the django variable has a state of submitted(enumerated as 5).

I tried

```
var submitted = {{variable.state == 5|yesno:"true,false" }}
```

but i get

```
Could not parse some characters: question.status| == 5||yesno:"true,false"
```

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:
Thank you guys for your help. 
I used

```
    var submitted = "{{variable.state}}" == 5;
```

and it worked as expected

Comment: Does it need to be `{% if variable.state == 5 %}true{%  else %}false{% endif %}`?

Comment: You can also write your custom template tag to make the js submitted `true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django expects a value or variable, not a statement with the [yesno builtin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno), hence the parsing error.

You should go with the easier solution that [HenryM already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715424/django-variables-in-script-tag#comment86444119_49715424) -

```
var submitted = {% if variable.state == 5 %}true{% else %}false{% endif %};
```